# Query to shuffle a string list stored with a separator in a string mysql database column

Tags: mysql

Is there a single query which can shuffle a string list which is stored in a string column?

E.g. the table has a column `list` like this:

```
list
----
a|e|q
k|w|z
...
```

I'm looking for a simple query which when excuted randomizes the lists, e.g. `a|e|q` becomes `e|q|a`, `k|w|z` becomes `w|k|z`, etc.

Is this possible with a single query?

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @nbk thanks, I'm aware of that, it's more like a curiosity

Comment: you have to split it and then order it randomly and then concat, but that is not possible in a "simple" query as you see in the link

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo for MySQL 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (list VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO mytable VALUE ('a|e|q'), ('k|w|z');

WITH m AS (SELECT list, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS r FROM mytable), 
n AS (SELECT 1 AS N UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3), 
x AS (SELECT m.r, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m.list, '|', n.n), '|', -1) AS val FROM n CROSS JOIN m) 
SELECT r, GROUP_CONCAT(val ORDER BY RAND() SEPARATOR '|') as list FROM x GROUP BY r;
```

Output if I run it repeatedly:

```
+---+-------+
| r | list  |
+---+-------+
| 1 | a|q|e |
| 2 | w|k|z |
+---+-------+

+---+-------+
| r | list  |
+---+-------+
| 1 | q|e|a |
| 2 | w|k|z |
+---+-------+

+---+-------+
| r | list  |
+---+-------+
| 1 | e|a|q |
| 2 | z|k|w |
+---+-------+
```